# How can I tell if the application is on top of the stack and what the activity is displayed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application with a number of activity, say A, B, C, D, E, F. .. activity and so on.

How can I tell if the application is on top of the stack and what the activity is displayed?

Comment: please explain a little more....

Comment: You don't have "applications" on the stack. An activity is on top of the stack if it is running; that is it's `onResume()` method has been called.

Answer (score 0):

that gives you a list of running processes, most recent first - so if the first app is yours it is on top of the stack. Probably not the best solution, but the only one I could think of at the moment

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)
getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes;
processes = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
int i = 1;
for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info: processes) {
    System.out.println(i++ + ": " + info.processName);
}
```

EDIT: So for your needs that would actually fit better since you just need the first one

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)
getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes;
processes = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo y = processes.get(0);
System.out.println("On top: " + y.processName);
```